# CSS Animation - Steps - to Animate Bookmark Star

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have the following code:

```js
let animation = document.getElementById('fave');
animation.addEventListener('click', function() {
  $(animation).toggleClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.fave {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fave img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: test_animate_reverse 1s steps(55);
}

.fave .animate {
  animation: test_animate 1s steps(55);
  left: -3519px;
}

@keyframes test_animate {
  from {left: 0;}
  to {left: -3519px;}
}

@keyframes test_animate_reverse {
  from {left: -3519px;}
  to {left: 0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="fave"><img src="https://cssanimation.rocks/images/posts/steps/twitter_fave_rectangle.png" id="fave"></section>
```

The target image is: https://cssanimation.rocks/images/posts/steps/twitter_fave_rectangle.png (albeit already modified so that all the images are positioned horizontally).

The result is quite satisfactory already. However, I have concerns:

1. As can probably be seen, my star always animates from the last frame of said image to the first frame whenever I refresh the browser window. If possible, I'd like it to not do that when I first refresh the window and only reverse-animate when I toggle it from 'active' to 'not active'.
2. I feel like using two `@keyframes` just to reverse an animation that is exactly the same is kind of inefficient. Is there a way to achieve the same effect without having to make an additional reverse `@keyframes`?
3. Is there a way for me to achieve the same effect without specifying the size of `section` explicitly when said `section` does not have a parent?
4. When I click quickly a few times on said image, if possible, I'd like it to finish its current animation first before proceeding to the next one. With my code now, preceding animations are immediately ended when a new animation is run.

**EDIT**

I've tried to not use the reverse `@keyframes` by changing to the following:

```
.fave img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: test_animate .7s steps(55);
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

What happened is the animation completely vanished.

Comment: Re: 2. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

Comment: @misorude Yes, I've read that before asking this question. However, how do I adjust it so that it may reverse when I toggle it from 'active' to 'not active'? The only way I can think of is to add another class. I have tried this, though. Please take a look at my edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the code from the actual [tutorial](https://cssanimation.rocks/twitter-fave/) where you got the image. It uses `transition` rather than `animation` and seems neater.

It will automatically reverse the animation too with the transition applied to the element.

You can set a disabled flag and use setTimeout() to prevent multiple clicks before the animation has finished.

```js
var click_disabled = false;

$('.fave').click(function() {
  
  if (click_disabled) {
    return; // do nothing
  }
 
  $(this).toggleClass('faved');
  
  // Set correct aria-label 
  var label = $(this).attr('aria-label') == 'Favourite' ? 'Unfavourite' : 'Favourite';
  
  $(this).attr('aria-label',label);
  
  click_disabled = true;
  
  // Timeout value should match transition length
  setTimeout(function(){
   click_disabled = false;
  }, 1000);
    
});
```

```css
.fave {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 45px;
  background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/shanomurphy/image/upload/v1547543273/fave_ltre0q.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(55);
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fave.faved {
  background-position: -3519px 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="fave" aria-label="Favourite"></button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `img` though, which is why `transition` isn't exactly working for me. However, I know that using `background-image` can achieve the same effect. So is it better just for me to `background-image`? I'm just not too fond of using that property to display things as if it were an object when it's actually a background.

Comment: I see no benefit of using an `img` element. In fact I imagine it should probably be a `button` element in any case (the original tutorial used a `section` element for some reason. I've updated my answer to use a button element and also use an `aria-label` for accessibility (value gets toggled via JavaScript depending on state).